# Undefine packageName and capture icon

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

I'm trying to give a get in the `Package Name` of the database directing app and indent the app's package icon and set it in an ImageView

Until now what I was able to build was this:

```
try {
    Cliente movieDetailsVO=myDb.getFav(0); // DB sqlite

    // Erro here next line --V
    Drawable icon=getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(movieDetailsVO.getCOLPM()); // <== get ID package app banco de dados
    imgIcon.setImageDrawable(icon);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

someone can help me...

---

**Sorted out**
    @aminography Helped me thank you very much for the attention

I got this way

```
Cliente movieDetailsVO = myDb.getFav(0);
txtMovieNameDisplay.setText(movieDetailsVO.getNAME());
String packageName = movieDetailsVO.getCOLPM(); 

try {

    Drawable icon = getContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
    imgIcon.setImageDrawable(icon);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ne) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get app icon and its launch `Intent` as following:

```
Cliente movieDetailsVO = myDb.getFav(0);
String packageName = movieDetailsVO.getCOLPM(); // Be sure about package name correctness

Drawable drawable = null;
try {
    drawable = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

// Try to use glide to show images into an ImageView
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(drawable).into(imgIcon);
```